# Can an event be independent to the Sample Space. Can a Null Event be independent to any other event?

Tags: probability, statistics

How do we show mathematically that event $A$ cannot be independent of $S$ the sample space?
How do we show event $A,$ if $P(A)=0$ cannot be independent of event $B$ if $0 < P(B) < 1?$

Seems like a dumb a question to me. A thing that exists cannot be independent of the universe that it is in, and a thing that does not exist is defined by the universe that it is not. Having tough time with the formulas.

Comment: But event $A$ clearly *is independent* of any event $B$,  because if $P(A) = 0$, then $A$ "doesn't happen" regardless of whether $B$ happens or not. So $B$ is not affecting the occurence of $A$.

Comment: That is what the formula says aswell. P(A|B)=0/P(B)=0=P(A). But shouldnt independence work both ways? P(B|A) = 0/0 = undefined. So independent one way, undefined the other?

Comment: $P(B|A)$ is not defined when $P(A) = 0$, because of division by zero. In that case, you go with the definition that $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$, which holds true if $P(A) = 0$. By the way, if $A$ is independent of $B$, then $B$ is independent of $A$, and the above formula clearly reflects that. In fact, we define independence of a set of events, not of one event over another in general.

Comment: What about the sample space? If A occurs then S occurs and does not change our knowledge of S because no matter what S occurs. And S occurring doesn't change P(A). Any event is independent of the sample space. Seems counter intuitive to say it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Any event is independent of the "sample space" event,as you say. See, when you say that two events are dependent, then the happening of one affects the other. If the road is dry, you drive at a certain speed, but when it is wet, you usually slow down. So the wetness of the road affects your speed. On the other hand, your speed is not affected by the sun rising in the east, because it rises in the east regardless of whether you are driving at 10 or 140 mph. So, the sun rising in the east, and the speed you drive at being equal to some value, are independent events.

Comment: Let me just double check the following corollary: an event with positive probability will be both independent and mutually exclusive to the empty set.

Comment: You are correct in making that statement.

Answer (score 3):

> How do we show mathematically that event $A$ cannot be independent of $S$ the sample space?

I think it's pretty unlikely that you would be able to show this, given that it's the opposite of true:

#### Every event $A$ is independent of the sample space $S$

**Proof:** For any event $A$, $P(A) = P(A \cap S)$ by definition of $S$, and since $S$ is the sample space, $P(S) = 1$. Therefore $P(A \cap S) = P(A) = P(A) * 1 = P(A) * P(S)$, which is the definition of what it means for $A$ and $S$ to be independent events.

Informally, since Event $S$ = "Something happens" describes the whole sample space, we can say *"Something always happens, independently of whether any other event $A$ happens."*

> How do we show event $A$, if $P(A) = 0$ cannot be independent of event $B$ if $0<P(B)<1$?

Again, this is the opposite of true:

#### Null events are independent of arbitrary events: If $P(A) = 0$ and $B$ is any event, $A$ and $B$ are independent.

**Proof:** Since $P(A) = 0$, we also have $P(A \cap B) \leq P(A) = 0$, so $P(A \cap B) = 0 = P(A) = P(A) * P(B)$, regardless of what $P(B)$ was. This is the definition of events $A$ and $B$ being independent.

As Teresa Lisbon helpfully reminds us, $P(A) = 0$ means that Event $A$ "practically never happens", and so we can informally restate this as, *"If Event $A$ practically never happens, then it practically never happens independently of whether any other event $B$ happens."*

Answer (score 0):

Taking the definition of independence of events $A$ and $B$ (in the same space)
to be $P(AB) = P(A)P(B),$ you have the following:

If $P(A)=0,$ then $P(AB)=0$ (because $AB \subset A$).
So $P(AB) = P(A)P(B) = 0$ and $A$ and $B$ are independent.

If $A = S,$ then $P(A) = 1$ and $P(AB) = P(B).$ So 
$P(AB) = P(A)P(B) = P(B)$ and $A$ and $B$ are independent.
(See comment by @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг.)

---

Sometimes one takes the definition of conditional probability
$P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B)$ to be the ***general multiplication rule*** $P(AB) = P(B)P(A|B),$ but that holds
*only* for events $B$ with $P(B) > 0$ because division by $0$ is impossible.

*Provided that* $P(B) > 0,$ it is fine to say intuitively "A independent of B" implies
$P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B) = P(A)P(B)/P(B) = P(A).$

---

The definition of independence of $A$ and $B$ does "go both ways" in
applications--in the following sense:

(a) If we are ***making*** a probability model and we "know" that
two coins are independent, then "getting heads on the first coin
and getting heads on the second" must satisfy $P(H_1H_2) = P(H_1)P(H_2)$
and then if we also "know" the coins are fair, a model consistent with what
we "know" *must* say $P(\text{Heads on both}) = P(H_1H_2) = (1/2)(1/2) = 1/4.$

(b) If we are ***given*** a probability model and told
that $P(A) = 1/3,$ $P(B) = 1/2,$ and $P(AB) = 1/6,$ then
$A$ and $B$ must be independent whether or not that seems intuitively obvious.
[Maybe $A$ has to do with occupation and $B$ with income, and we find
it difficult to believe the events can be independent. We can say we
don't believe the given model, nevertheless the given model does imply independence of $A$ and $B$.]